# How to handle the sequence about cancel and call async API in viewcontroller life cycle

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, lifecycle

I have a tabbarVC embed two viewcontrollers, VC1 and VC2.
In VC `viewWillAppear` I will call the API, and `viewWillDisappear` I will cancel the API .
I face a problem, when I in VC1 switch to VC2, and VC2's API be canceled.
How to handle viewcontroller life cycle have sequence in this situation?
I use Moya and Alamofire in this project.

VC1:

```
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("VC1 call API")
    callAPI()
}

func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("VC1 cancel API")
    cancelAPI()
}
```

VC2:

```
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("VC2 call API")
    callAPI()
}

func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("VC2 cancel API")
    cancelAPI()
}
```

Log: VC1 -> VC2 (API be canceled)

```
VC2 call API
VC1 cancel API
```

Comment: I’m not clear what the question is. “when I in VC1 switch to VC2, and VC2's API be canceled” … No, your log is saying that VC1’s API call is cancelled, not VC2’s.

Comment: Now, I’m presuming that `callAPI` is unique to each view controller/model. If you’re saying that VC1’s “cancel” is canceling VC2’s “call” (i.e. the same API call is used by each, then you probably want to abstract this network layer out of the view controllers (and not “cancel” on `viewWillDisappear`).